# What on earth is an 'fword ptr'?

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86

I was running a game's executable file through a disassembler and saw the following instruction:

```
1090103D: FF 6D 77           jmp         fword ptr [ebx+77h]
```

I'm used to seeing `byte ptr` (8-bit), `word ptr` (16-bit), `dword ptr` (32-bit) and `qword ptr` (64-bit) in disassembly dumps.

The term "F-word" has a slightly different meaning to me; does anyone know what it means in this context?

Comment: It's unlikely what you're looking at is actually code. Far jumps are pretty much useless in 32-bit user mode code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a 48 bit pointer used in a far jump. It indicates it is a jump to a 16 bit segment/selector address with an associated offset address.